# Highcharts Dynamic different time calculate

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highchats.com Dynamic update showed two ways to calculate time in her examples (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) and (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/).

1: On series, the time is calculate this way:

```
time = (new Date()).getTime();
...
x: time + i * 1000, //Multiplying by 1000 (mileseconds)
```

2: But on Event load  setInterval() it's calculated in the other diferente way:

```
x = (new Date()).getTime(), //Without multiplying by 1000.
```

Why this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't multiplying `time` by 1000.  They are multiplying `i` by 1000 and adding it to time.  `i` goes from -19 to 0.  So they get 20 points, each one second apart before the current time.

They could have also done:

```
for (i = -19000; i <= 0; i += 1000) {
    data.push({
       x: time + i,
       y: Math.random()
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure! the basic mathematics rule: first multiplication, addition after. Thank you